# Python pivot table for large file in chunks: memory error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Using a bunch of dataframe chunks that look like this, where Version and ASSAY together form a unique identifier:

```
   Version  ASSAY   Resp_Rob_Sigmas
0    A123    F           0.56
1    B234    G           0.78
2    C345    R           0.9
3    D456    F           1.0
4    D456    G           0.3
```

I'm creating a pivot table needs to look like this:

```
        F      G      R
A123   0.56   NA     NA
B234   NA     0.78   NA
C345   NA     NA     0.9
D456   1.0    0.3    NA
```

Pre-chunking and pre-unzipping, the data frame is 13 GB, so the pivot table explodes in size during creation causing a memory error. My current code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

# Number of lines to be read at a time from csv
chunk_size = 10 ** 5
merged_df = pd.DataFrame([])
folder = zipfile.ZipFile(OP_DIRECTORY + "/file.zip")

# Reading csv in chunks, dropping columns, dropping rows with null responses.
for chunk in pd.read_csv(folder.open("file.csv"), chunksize=chunk_size):
    df = pd.DataFrame(chunk)
    # Operations on df
    ...
    ... 
    merged_df = merged_df.append(df)

# Pivoting data to create matrix
df = pd.pivot_table(merged_df, index=['Version'], values=['Resp_Rob_Sigmas'], columns=['ASSAY'])
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

How can I prevent a memory error and optimize this?

Comment: could you not write each pivoted chunk to csv, then load them and concat them? otherwise pivot is a very expensive operation already so may need to start using stuff like dask or hdf5 to handles this

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this using pandas and not something else?

Comment: maybe using unstack ? `df.set_index(['Version','ASSAY']).unstack()`

Comment: I'll try the unstack @Wen. Is there a more efficient way without pandas, @gobrewers14?

Comment: @PearlPhilip then you can look at numpy, also , need to change your original dataframe to array

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I have exact same problem